# Parsing PNG as PHP via htaccess works only on local server but not on webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, parsing, png, image

I have created a dynamic PNG-picture in PHP. In order to use the PNG extension I created a .htaccess-File with the following content:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .png
```

On my local XAMPP server everything works perfect, but after uploading the files on a webserver it doesn' t work anymore. When I access the file, the PHP-Code of the file is displayed.
These are the 2 different answers from both servers:

**Local Server:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 21:51:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Last-Modified: Sat, 07 Feb 2009 11:47:04 GMT
Etag: "9000000024598-1e66-46252b23c9e00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7782
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/x-icon
```

**Webserver:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 21:55:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 21:21:56 GMT
Etag: "db0f1b0-afc-4cc33be6befa5"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2812
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
```

So somehow the file doesn' t get parsed. I really don' t know where to start here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd better use a `.htaccess` with the RewriteEngine like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/to/dynamic_image
RewriteRule ^logo\.png$ logo.php
```

Or for all .php files :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/to/dynamic_image
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! But I am still wondering why my solution only works on one server.

Comment: You may look at [here](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php/). Some `.htaccess` directive are or are not allowed according to your web hosting.

Answer (score 2):

in your php file set the header as a png image (BEFORE any output to the page):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// image generating code here.......
?>
```

This does away with the need for the .htaccess entry

Comment: I already did that. File doesn' t get parsed anyway. Perhaps I didn t make it clear in my post but when I access the file on the webserver it displays the SOURCE CODE of the file